# Posting a file with cURL doesn't work with @ at the beginning of the path

Tags: php, file, post, curl

So I'm trying to send files to another page using cURL, along with other POST variables. Most of it works, except the file sending. But it only doesn't work on my localhost. When it's uploaded to the hosted web server, it works exactly like it should.

I also don't want to use CURLFile because the web server doesn't support it.

Here is the code:

```
        // Output the image
        imagejpeg($fileData['imageBackground'], $newFileName, 75);

        // Get Old Background
        $query['getBackground'] = $this->PDO->prepare("SELECT backgroundImage FROM accounts WHERE token = :token");
        $query['getBackground']->execute(array(':token' => $token));

        $queryData = $query['getBackground']->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $verificationKey = self::newVerificationKey($token);
        // Send the file to the remote
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uploadURL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        $postArgs = array(
                'action' => 'updateBackground',
                'verificationKey' => $verificationKey,
                'file' => '@' . realpath($newFileName),
                'oldBackground' => $queryData['backgroundImage']
            );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postArgs);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        unlink($newFileName);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your webserver is running an older version which supports the "@" - but not curlfile. Your local machine supports curlfile - but not the "@" (in the default configuration)...

You can use

```
if (class_exists("CurlFile")){
   $postArgs = array(
                'action' => 'updateBackground',
                'verificationKey' => $verificationKey,
                'file' => new CurlFile($newFileName),
                'oldBackground' => $queryData['backgroundImage']
            );
}else{
 $postArgs = array(
                'action' => 'updateBackground',
                'verificationKey' => $verificationKey,
                'file' => '@' . realpath($newFileName),
                'oldBackground' => $queryData['backgroundImage']
            );
}
```

which is recommended, because the `@`-way is considered unsafe, so use `CurlFile`, when available.

However, to have the `@`-way working lokaly as well, you can use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
```

This defaulted to `false` prior to PHP 5.5, but defaults to `true` for later versions.

Note, play arround with the "order". There seems to be an issue with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` beeing somewhat sensitive to existing options. So

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postArgs);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
```

might not work, while

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postArgs);
```

might.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I just did the whole class_exists way, and it works perfectly. Thanks!